# Vector insertion in Binary Search Tree in linear time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

i have a vector eg.vector{3, 4, 1, 0, 9, 2, 7}
and i want to insert all the element's of vector into the binary search tree in O(N) time.

i did the insertion in n*height(root) complexity by passing each element of vector at a time (By searching in a BST to find exact position of element.).

output for above vector == > [3, 1, 4, 0, 2, null, 9, null, null, null, null, 7]

Comment: i have a small question, do you want to insert the vector's element in the same order?

Comment: Yes the order should maintain.

Comment: i suggest you can apply AVL tree directly or a black-red tree, it's better in your case i think. and you can find something useful in this question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100192/which-is-faster-sorting-a-vector-then-putting-it-into-an-avl-tree-or-inputtin

Comment: thanks @walidbarakat but it didn't help me.

Comment: @walidbarakat we can figure out a tree is binary search tree or not in linear time, then i think it is possible to insert in BST in linear as well.

Comment: i guess it's not possible to do it in a linear time, in BST you need to do more than re-balancing which can't allow you to have the linear time complexity you want